# Are these Delirium stories from The Sandman #21 discussed elsewhere in comics?

Tags: comics, episode-identification, the-sandman, vertigo-comics

In *The Sandman* #21, Delirium briefly discusses two humans that she had encountered (supposedly in recent history). There was a man who wanted to kiss her, who she made to see only "pretty colors" (p 14), and a girl who will "always be happy for ever and ever and ever" (p 17).

[image: "I met this guy in this club in - somewhere. This club. Late at night. I don't know where it was. He wanted to kiss me. But I don't like to be touched. So I did this stuff to him, so he saw only colors. Real pretty colors, though. ...pretty."]

[image: "I met this little girl and she said she thought I was pretty. She was SO nice. So I DID something to here. Something so she'll always be happy. Always be HAPPY for EVER and EVER and EVER."]

(Somehow, I doubt the little girl is better off after her encounter with Delirium. I'm picturing something like [Joker gas](https://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/batman/images/2/21/JokerVenomVictim.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20170222124647).)

**Are these stories told more fully elsewhere in comics (either in the "Sandman Library" or in other comics)?**

Comment: Nah, they're not. Period.

Comment: I'm rummaging through my memories now, but I'm 90% sure there aren't any stories depicting Delirium before the events of this volume (there's a caveat, but it doesn't invalidate my point).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The answer seems to be negative.**

In my opinion, those lines are there to paint us a picture of Delirium - a chaotic, unpredictable, and truly (wait for it) mad person[ification].

What she does is sometimes out of proportion, sometimes lacks causality, and is almost always not what you'd expect from a sane person.

But to answer your actual question, those stories don't get more coverage in other comics. *Arguably*, the little girl she talks about could be the girl seen in chapter 5 - "Delirium: Going Inside" - of *Endless Nights*:

[image]

I'm purposefully not adding more context; in short, this story is set after the events of the main series, and Delirium is having a sort of nervous breakdown, and is lost in her own domain. This girl's mother claims that she was **catatonic** for over a year; maybe this was Delirium's understanding of "happy for ever and ever and ever".

**However**, the chronology does not match up - the events of the main *Sandman* run spanned over more than a year, so this is not the girl Delirium spoke of in issue #21. It may, however, be a link to that event. Maybe.

Comment: There's also mention of "a man who sees rainbows" in the picture you've included (but you can tell me if that's something else).

Comment: Don't know who that is (3 am, brain not working) :(

Comment: Go to sleep!! Now! :)

Comment: @Shokhet "the man who sees rainbows" was part of the "rescue team" created to save Delirium - it was a group of insane people guided by a talking dog.

Comment: @Yasskier That's what I meant by "purposefully not adding more context" :)

Comment: If one keeps asking for spoilers, one will get spoilers. Although in this case it'd not really a spoiler

Comment: @Yasskier True that :)